# Using middleware with app.use

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

what is the difference between:

```
function setLocale(req, res, next) {
    req.params.locale = req.params.locale || 'pt';

    res.cookie('locale', req.params.locale);
    req.i18n.setLocale(req.params.locale);
    console.log(req.params.locale);

    next();
}



app.get('/:locale?', setLocale, function(req, res) {
    res.render("index");
});
```

And this:

```
app.use(setLocale);

function setLocale(req, res, next) {
    req.params.locale = req.params.locale || 'pt';

    res.cookie('locale', req.params.locale);
    req.i18n.setLocale(req.params.locale);
    console.log(req.params.locale);

    next();
}



app.get('/:locale?', function(req, res) {
    res.render("index");
});
```

??

Only the first is working, if i try to use app.use, the code will broke cause req.params.locale will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

`app.use` will add the middleware to the stack and use it before each request is processed, always, regardless of route, method etc.

In the first example the middleware is added as a callback function to that route only, as `app.get` accepts multiple callbacks, and calling `next` moves to the next callback etc

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) { 
                 next();  // move to next
             }, function(req, res, next) {
                 // continues here when next() is called in previous callback etc.    
             });
```

this means that in the first example the `setLocale` function is only called when the route matches `/:locale?`, while in the second example using `app.use` will always call the `setLocale` function before the routes callback is executed.

Unfortunately `req.params` is not available in `app.use` as it depends on the router and is added later, so you're probably stuck with including the function as a callback to every route, and you could probably do that with `app.all('*')`

```
function setLocale(req, res, next) {
    req.params.locale = req.params.locale || 'pt';

    res.cookie('locale', req.params.locale);
    req.i18n.setLocale(req.params.locale);

    next();
}

app.all('*', setLocale);

app.get('/:locale?', function(req, res) {
    res.render("index");
});
```

Comment: that's such a shame.. i want use the setLocale in all my routes, there is anyone that i can use without having to declare before the callback??

Comment: That's what `app.use` does, it runs the function before all your routes ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you use `app.use(setLocale);` all you calls will be passed that function. Even if you call the url `/` that code will run and then param will be undefined.

The fisrt option you have (`app.get('/:locale?', setLocale,`) you use that function **only** when that url matches and there is a `locale` that you can use inside the function.

Comment: so i need declare the setLocale in all my routes? =/

Comment: @DRX if you want to use `app.use(setLocale);` as case 2 (generally) you have at least to avoid that `undefined`. You could do `if (!req.params || !('locale' in req.params)) return next();` as first line of that function.